# SQL Server insert values floating point value is out of range

Tags: sql-server

I try to insert rows into my table:

```
INSERT INTO data (A, B) 
VALUES (`1-20.csv`, `https:/someurl/5642a1613e3eb.csv`)
```

but I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[22003]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The floating point value '5642a1613e3eb' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes).

Apparently it misinterprets the string.

Comment: You are using the wrong quote marks. Use the single quote.

Comment: you need to add your table structure

Comment: What are the **data types** of your columns `A` and `B` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quote <kbd>'</kbd> to enclose strings, not a backtick <kbd>`</kbd>